# Parameterize query not limiting in mssql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a project am working on and I have been testing my queries to see how they work but the problem is when I passed a parameter to the query it is not limiting it to that parameter I passed.

Here is the query syntax:

```
SELECT C.*,
           F.Bank_VNO,
           F.sname
    FROM   customer C
           LEFT JOIN fssign F
                  ON c.cust_no = f.cust_no
                     AND F.cust_no = '100055'
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT Min(ac_no) ac_no
                      FROM   loans
                      WHERE  full_paid = '0'
                      GROUP  BY ac_no) AS l
                  ON c.cust_no = l.ac_no
                     AND cust_type = 'BUS'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not very clear what you mean, but may be you should remove GROUP BY:

```
 SELECT C.*
        ,F.Bank_VNO
        ,F.sname
    FROM customer C
    LEFT JOIN fssign F ON c.cust_no = f.cust_no
                AND F.cust_no = '100055'
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT MIN(ac_no) ac_no
                FROM loans
                WHERE full_paid = '0'
/*              GROUP BY ac_no */
        ) AS l ON c.cust_no = l.ac_no
        AND cust_type = 'BUS'
```

May be that query you want to write is:

```
SELECT C.*
      ,F.Bank_VNO
      ,F.sname
FROM customer C
INNER JOIN fssign F ON c.cust_no = f.cust_no                    
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(ac_no) ac_no
            FROM loans
            WHERE full_paid = '0'   
            ) AS l ON c.cust_no = l.ac_no
WHERE  C.cust_type = 'BUS'
 AND  F.cust_no = '100055'
```

Comment: it is still bringing the same result as mine.

Comment: Did you try the second query?

Comment: but inner join won't bring any result if both tables are not equal unlike left join. When I run it it didn't show any result because both tables criteria are not equal.

Comment: pls post in your question text with actual result and expected results (text, not images), so we could try to help you

Answer (score 0):

`Left Join` will not filter records. It will bring all the records from left table, unless you put the filter in `Where` clause.

I think you want the records only when `cust_type = 'BUS'`. Move the filter to `Where` clause. Assuming `cust_type` column is from `customer` table

```
SELECT C.*,
           F.Bank_VNO,
           F.sname
    FROM   customer C
           LEFT JOIN fssign F
                  ON c.cust_no = f.cust_no
                     AND F.cust_no = '100055'
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT Min(ac_no) ac_no
                      FROM   loans
                      WHERE  full_paid = '0'
                      GROUP  BY ac_no) AS l  -- This query does not make more sense
                  ON c.cust_no = l.ac_no
Where C.cust_type = 'BUS'
```